# Votes/answers/views and question title end up in two separate rows

Tags: bug, design

[image]

I think it's a bit unpleasant, lots of wasted space... is it a bug or a feature?

Using Chrome on OSX Mavericks, btw.

**EDIT:** I double checked with Safari and FF, it looks ok. Also Chrome running on Mint 14 looks fine as well. The problem seems to be specific to Chrome on OSX :s

Comment: This bug happened on Chrome at 110% zoom, but that was fixed very recently. Do you use an unusual zoom level even above 110%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me when I wasn't using the default rendering size. In Chrome, make sure that there isn't the little magnifying glass in the URL bar suggesting that you're not viewing at the default zoom level.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely appears to be a bug. I can't reproduce it on either Chrome or Firefox under Mavericks. I would first check, though, if you have a plug-in that's influencing this behavior.

Comment: dont use any extensions beyond Ad-blocker Plus

Comment: Check that, maybe? As I said, this isn't something I'm seeing in Chrome. Does this persist as you resize the window?

Comment: Disabling ABP does not help, also I have ABP on my linux machine as well, which looks OK.